# Unique continuos linear function given a continuous function from a dense space in X to Y (Y is a Banach Space).

Tags: derivatives, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space, let $Y$ be a Banach Space, let $D\subseteq X$ be a dense linear subspace of $X$ and let $L:D\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous linear function. Then there is a unique continuous linear function $M:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $M|_D=L$.

The task is to prove this theorem. I have no idea where to even start, any direction you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

edit: " Banach Space, let $D\in X$ " [;\rightarrow ;] "" Banach Space, let $D\subseteq X$ ""

Comment: This is a particular case of the unique extension of uniformly continuous functions. Basically, this is due to the fact that a uniformly continuous function sends a Cauchy sequence to a Cauchy sequence. So if the range is complete...

Comment: Following julien's suggestion, pick $x\in X\setminus D$ and let $x_n$ be a sequence approaching $x$ (this is possible by density of $D$ in $X$). Then $x_n$ must be Cauchy. Show that $L(x_n)$ is Cauchy. Use completeness of $Y$ to show that $L(x_n)$ has a limit. Now how would you define $M(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

More general version: $X$ is a metric space, $Y$ a complete metric space,  $D\subseteq X$ is dense, and $L:D\to Y$ is uniformly continuous. A continuous extension $M: X\to Y$ can be defined by 
$$\{M(x)\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \overline{L(B(x,1/n))} \tag1$$
where $B(x,1/n)$ is open ball centered at $x$ with radius $1/n$. Uniform continuity guarantees that the intersection in (1) has *at most one* element, while completeness makes sure it's *exactly one* element. It is straightforward to check that $M$ is uniformly continuous (with the same modulus of continuity). And in the context of linear maps between normed spaces, one can check that $M$ is linear as well.